# How to keep a certain number of Docker containers running the same application and add/remove them as needed?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I've working with Docker containers. What Ive done is lunching 5 containers running the same application, I use HAProxy to redirect requests to them, I added a volume to preserve data and set restart policy as Always.
It works. (So far this is my load balancing aproach)But sometimes I need another container to join the pool as there might be more requests, or maybe at first I don't need 5 containers.

Answer (score 1):

This is provided by the Swarm Mode addition in Docker 1.12. It includes orchestration that lets you not only scale your service up or down, but recover from an outage by automatically rescheduling the jobs to run on other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Docker 1.12 (yet!), you can also use a Service Discovery like Consul, register your containers inside and use a tool like Consul Template to regenerate your load balancer configuration accordingly.

I made a talk 6 months ago about it. You can find the code and the configuration I used during my demo here: https://github.com/bargenson/dockerdemo